# C# UWP (If counter never increase)

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to create something like... If counter never increase for 5 seconds, then something happens. I tried (counter != counter++) , but Idk is this the correct way to deal with this type of situation. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You need to save your previous counter value when it was updated and then compare it the newly updated value.

Comment: `counter != counter++` will *never* return true, as the `++` is evaluated *after* the comparison . Your statement is thus equivalent to the following:  `counter != counter; counter++`. What do you *actually* want to achieve? Please show some code demonstrating your issue.

Comment: @IpsitGaur How do I save my previous counter value and compare it to the new one ?

Comment: Create a new var like 
var previouscounter = counter;

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish, like Ipsit Gaur wrote.
Maybe you're looking for something along these lines where you every 5 seconds check if counter has changed compared to it's previous value?

```
TimeSpan period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
Float previousCounter;

ThreadPoolTimer PeriodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) =>
    {
    //
    if (counter == previousCounter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nothing happened for 5 seconds");


        Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () => {
        //Affect gui?
        });
    }
    previousCounter = counter;
}, period);
```

Comment: I haven't run the code above, but it should be something along those lines and hopefully it gives you a general idea on how one solution might be. 
At the end of the loop, we update previousCounter.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try